# Connecting to MySQL with PHP Gives SQL Sytax Error

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I'm new at PHP and SQL, so I was playing around with this table stuff, but it won't work.  What's wrong with this script?  I get this error:

```
"Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '')' at line 3"
```

The PHP script:

```
<?php
$mysql_host = "localhost";
$mysql_database = "database";
$mysql_user = "username";
$mysql_password = "password";
$con = mysql_connect($mysql_host,$mysql_user,$mysql_password);
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO Persons (name, age)
VALUES
('$_POST[name]','$_POST[age])";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "1 record added";

mysql_close($con)
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out, you missed a single quote just before the closing parenthesis.

Also, you should never use POST values in the fashion:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO Persons (name, age)
VALUES
('$_POST[name]','$_POST[age]')";
```

Use this:

```
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[name]);
$age = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[age]);

$sql="INSERT INTO Persons (name, age) VALUES ('$name','$age')";
```

This is to prevent SQL injection attacks.

EDIT: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/379892 . You'll find more details on preventing SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Yep, the sanitizing was my next step.  I just hadn't gotten there yet.

Answer (score 4):

add Apostrophe

```
$sql="INSERT INTO Persons (name, age)
VALUES
('$_POST[name]','$_POST[age]')"
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed a closing apostrophe:

```
('$_POST[name]','$_POST[age]')";
```

Comment: Oh, and insert standard comments regarding sanitisation of form input when working with databases, SQL Injection, and all that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql="INSERT INTO Persons (name, age)
VALUES
('$_POST[name]','$_POST[age])";
```

should be

```
$sql="INSERT INTO Persons (name, age)
VALUES
('$_POST[name]','$_POST[age]')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this part in and see what result you get:

```
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $con);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die ('Can\'t use foo : ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, shouldn't it be like this?

`$sql="INSERT INTO Persons (name, age)
VALUES
('{$_POST['name']}','{$_POST['age']}')";`